# How to split images depend on it's label so each label will have it's image's folder

Tags: python, csv, machine-learning

I have a csv file which contain images label and path, and I have another folder contain all images, so I want to save each label's images in it's own folder, here how the csv looks like, I appreciate any help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSf3p.png)

I didn't find any code for this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `pandas` for reading the csv, `os` for creating the folders e `shutil` for copying files.

```
import os
import shutil
import pandas as pd

# read the file
csv_file = pd.read_csv('file.csv', dtype=str)

# create the folders
labels = csv_file['label']
for label in labels:
    os.makedirs(label, exist_ok=True)    

# iterate rows and copy images
for _, row in csv_file.iterrows():
    label = row['label']
    path = row['path']
    img_name = os.path.split(path)[-1]
    new_path = os.path.join(label, img_name)
    shutil.copy(path, new_path)
```